# Why does the Java CompletableFuture API uses long + TimeUnit instead of Duration?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java 9 introduced many new methods in the CompletableFuture API that support execution timeouts.
For example:

```
public CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout​(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);

public CompletableFuture<T> completeOnTimeout​(T value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

More can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeOnTimeout-T-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).

These methods take a `long` and a `TimeUnit` as arguments. Is there a specific reason it has been done so? Wouldn't `Duration` be a better choice here?

```
public CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout​(Duration duration);

public CompletableFuture<T> completeOnTimeout​(T value, Duration duration);
```

Comment: My **guess** is that, since Duration was just introduced in Java 8, they either didn't think of it, or decided it was "too new" and stuck with a more traditional and usual implementation.

Comment: I would guess for the reason @user949300 said, and also much of the rest of the Java concurrency API uses `TimeUnit` (because `Duration` didn't exist at that point) so this way it's consistent.

Comment: I feel that overloaded methods with both styles would have been better. That is how you slowly push the users towards newer (and objectively better) API.